# How to handle data skew in Spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a structured streaming application with aggregation, and there are a few tasks that take a long time due data skew.

I tried to add salting, with multiple "groupBy"s, but multiple aggregations are not supported in structured streaming. Here is an example:

```
    df = df.withColumn("salt", floor(rand() * 10))
    df = df.groupBy("my_field","salt").agg(sum("num_field").as("total"))
    df = df.groupBy("my_field").agg(sum("total"))
```

What is the right way to handle this (Spark 2.3.1)?

Comment: Try using `Df.repartition(x)` that helped us with our skew issue in our streaming pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. repartition by the groupBy field? any idea why it helped? groupBy is also kind of repartitioning.

Comment: You should try doing `repartition` before group by. Our dataframe were skewed across many executors, with repartition we are reducing the number of partitions in dataframe, that lead to less data shuffle in later approach. Another Spark option worth trying is `coalesce` if you think you micro batch can fit in single executor, that would also avoid shuffling.